# WinForm Control event handlers order

Tags: c#, winforms, events, custom-controls

I want to understand which one will called first:

- Standard event handler subscriber method, like `void TextBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`
- Control's native handler aka `base.OnMouseClick(e)` that has been declared in control's source code;

I want to override standard control's action but I am not sure about when to call the base method `base.OnMouseClick(e)`, after my code or before it.

Can somebody help to clarify control's event handler order to make the right decision?

Comment: It depends to the requirement of your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Control.OnMouseClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx) calls event handlers. Actually, as you can see from the documentation, it does nothing else:

> Raises the MouseClick event.

So, you should be able to control an order of execution in a relatively straightforward way:

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before handlers");
    base.OnMouseClick(e);
    Console.WriteLine("After handlers");
}

void TextBox_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Handler");
}
```

This might not work if one of your parent controls breaks the contract of `OnMouseDown` (e.g. overrides it without calling base method).

Answer (score 2):

`OnMouseDown` is basically just responsible to raise `MouseDown` event. This is what is done in `OnMouseDown` method of `Control` class:

```
protected virtual void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    Contract.Requires(e != null);
    MouseEventHandler handler = (MouseEventHandler)Events[EventMouseDown];
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

Then based on the requirements, child controls override `OnMouseDown` to do something. For example:

- `DataGridView` overrides it and first calls `base.OnMouseDown` ad then hit-tests to check if mouse down has been done on a cell and then calls `OnCellMouseDown`.
- `ToolStrip` overrides it and first hit-tests the mouse position to check if it's on an item it raises `MouseDown` event of the `ToolStripItem`. *Otherwise* it calls `base.OnMouseDown`.

**Important Note**: Keep in mind, when overriding `OnMouseDown` if you don't call `base.OnMouseDown` then the custom logic which exists in `OnMouseDown` method of the base control will not run. In addition, `MouseDown` event will not raise!

Comment: Then if will not call base.OnMouseDown in a custom control overrided method the MouseDown event of that control will not be called, does it?

Comment: If you don't call `base.OnMouseDown` the custom logic which probably exists in the base control will not run. In addition, `MouseDown` event will not raise!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Now on mouse click backcolor of Textbox will be changed to Red. Now we want to change this behavior we want Green Color in mouse click.

```
public class MyTextBox1 : MyTextBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Here is the answer of your question if you call base.OnMouseClick(e); first then your desired result will be Green and if you call base.OnMouseClick(e); at last your end result will be Red as in base class.

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
     BackColor = Color.Green;
     base.OnMouseClick(e);

}
```

Comment: Yes, i got this. But if i will subscribe on MyTextBox.Click in some class will the base method called first or the in-some-class event handler?

Comment: If you use this control and subscribe Mouse click event base method will be invoked automatically.